# What is the appropriate frequency and start/end date in R for ts()?

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I have the following dataset which I want to make a time series object of for auto.arima forecasting:

```
head(df)

total_score return
1539    121.77          
1074    422.18          
901    -229.79          
843     96.30           
1101   -55.25           
961    -48.28
```

This data set contains of 13104 rows with each row representing sentiment score of tweets and BTC return on hourly basis, i.e. first row is 2021-01-01 00:00 and second row is 2021-01-01 01:00 and so on up until 2022-06-30 23:00. I have looked up how many hours fits in this range and that is 13103. How can I make my ts function such that I can use it for forecasting purposes in R auto.arima?
Moreover, I understand that auto.arima takes homoscedastic errors, whereas I need it to work for heteroscedastic errors. I also read that for this, I might use a GARCH model. However, if my auto.arima functions results in using a order of (2,0,0), does this mean that my GARCH model should be a (0,0,2)?

PS: I am still confused on why my data seems to be stationary, I was under the impression that crypto currencies are most likely NOT stationary, that is, the returns as well. But that is something for another time.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: A. Jahanyar, what do you want to forecast?

Comment: @Isaiah, I would like to forecast the Bitcoin prices based on the sentiment score of tweets containing the word Bitcoin. The data of Bicoin consist of hourly data as well as the sentiment score. However, I understand that frequency can either be daily, quarterly, monthly or yearly. I am just a bit confused what to enter for the frequency if you use hourly data. The difficult part is that the once I use the frequency value equal to the number of observations in my Bitcoin data set, I am not sure what to use for the start period of my time series and end date of my time series.

Comment: Frequency is mainly of interest if you expect seasonal patterns. In your case you probable have daily patterns: so a frequency of 24 would make sense; but you probably also have weekly patterns; so a frequency of 24*7 would also make sense. See https://otexts.com/fpp2/complexseasonality.html for more info on this. The start is not that important (except in plots); if you use a frequency of 24 and a start time of c(1,0), this means that your start time is hour 0 on day 1.